# matching multiple lines beginning with whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple regex syntax to match lines that begin with exactly 4 spaces.

```
/^(\s{4}).*/g
```

The problem is that the `.` token matches everything except a new line so multiple lines beginning with 4 spaces, only the first line is matched. I've tried explicitly matching `\n` tokens but I haven't been able to quite get the results I need. I've been testing this using regexr.com [here](http://regexr.com/3clhb) I can't use any syntax that isn't supported by javascript.

Comment: You just  forgot the `/m` modifier. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF6bR3/1)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realize that was an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` symbol can denote 2 things: a beginning of string, or a beginning of a line. To make it denote the latter, you need to specify the `/m` MULTILINE modifier:

```
/^(\s{4}).*/gm
```

Or - to only match literal regular spaces (note that `\s`can also match newlines):

```
/^( {4}).*/gm
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF6bR3/1)